# Having trouble using Haskell group

Tags: haskell

I am studying Haskell in advance for next semester and I am stuck testing **group**. I tried directly in **WinGHCi** and writing a function in a text file. Reading documentation (haskell.org, zvon.org) I see that the module **Data.List** is required so I did the following in **WinGHCi**:

```
:l Data.List
```

But I get an error: *: module ‘Data.List’ is a package module*

Then, I wrote a function using a text editor as follows:

```
import Data.List
group "aaaabbbbbbbccddd"
```

I get an error again when loading (compiling):

```
_Haskell.hs:2:1:
Parse error: naked expression at top level
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell_
```

I am a complete beginner in functional programming. I will very much appreciate your help to fix my issue.

Best regards.

Comment: Give your expression a name; e.g. `import Data.List; result = group "aaaabbbbbbbccddd"`. Then you will be able to load your file in `ghci`. If you want to compile, the easiest will be to also provide a `main`, such as `main = print result`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it in GHCI just fine, exactly as you're importing it in the text file.

```
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> group "aaaaabbbbbbcccccddd"
["aaaaa","bbbbbb","ccccc","ddd"]
```

Naked expression at top level means exactly that: you can't have a naked expression at top level. Try this in a text file.

```
import Data.List

testGroup :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
testGroup lst = group lst
```

That will work wonders.

```
~/temp ❯❯❯ ghci h.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( h.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> testGroup [2]
[[2]]
```

Comment: Noice `testGroup = group` so it's rather redundant.

Comment: It totally is, I just wanted to show what a 'naked expression' was meant, although this maybe wasn't the best way. Most probably, if you just want to test group, you'll do it just in GHCI